# Spark Installation

Tags: java, openjdk

I have installed and checked it with the command `java -version` which gave the following output:

> openjdk version "1.8.0_162"
>       OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-8u162-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12)
>       OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)

After that I downloaded spark 2.3.0 and tried to install it. At the last step, when I am trying to run the command at the location:

```
$SPARK_PATH sbin/start-all.sh
```

The output is as below:

> starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master,
>   logging to /usr/lib/spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark--  org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-ubuntu.out
>   failed to launch: nice -n 0 /usr/lib/spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host ubuntu --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
>     /usr/lib/spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class:
>   line 71: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java:
>   cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I don't know what I am missing here.
I need some help!

**P.S:** The output of `jps` is:

```
14531 Worker
14568 Jps
```

Comment: bash: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: Okay, how can I fix this issue??

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have `JAVA_HOME` in *spark-env.sh* set to the working open JDK version you have installed.